# PHP and MySQL Output Problems

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having a big problem with this php code. I can't seem to get a result out when I enter in a Professor ssn. I've tried output and and several different ways of echo.

```
 <html>
  2 <head>
  3         <title>CPSC332 Term Project</title>
  4 </head>
  5
  6 <?php
  7 $output = NULL;
  8
  9 if(isset($_POST['sub_ssn']))
 10 {
 11
 12         $mysqli = NEW MySQLi("host", "user", "pswd", "database");
 13
 14         $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ssn']);
 15
 16         $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT title, classroom, meeting_days, start_time, end_time FROM Sections, Course WHERE course_num = course_numb        er AND ssn = '$ssn'");
 17
 18         if($resultSet->num_rows > 0)
 19         {
 20                 while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc($resultSet))
 21                 {
 22
 23                         $stringTest = $row['title'];
 24                         echo $stringTest;
 25                 }
 26         }
 27         else
 28         {
 29
 30         }
 31
 32
 33 }
 34
 35 ?>
 36
 37 <body>
 38         For the professors:<br>
 39         a. Given the social security numbe rof a professor, list the titles, classrooms, meeting days and time of his/her classes.
 40         <form method = "POST">
 41                 Professor SSN: <input type="text" name="ssn">
 42                 <input type="submit" name="sub_ssn" value="Submit">
 43         </form>
 44         b. Given a course number and a section number, count how many students get each distinct grade, i.e. 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', etc.
 45         <form action='' method='POST'>
 46                 Course Number: <input type='text' name='cnum'><br>
 47                 Section Number: <input type='text' name='snum'>
 48                 <input type='submit' value='Submit'><br>
 49         </form>
 50         For the students:<br>
 51         a. Given a course number list the sections of the course, including the classrooms, the meetings days and time, and the number of students en        rolled in each section.
 52         <form action='' method='POST'>
 53                 Course Number: <input type='text' name='cnum'>
 54                 <input type='submit' value='Submit'><br>
 55         </form>
 56         b. Given the campus wide ID of a student, list all courses the student took and the grades.
 57         <form action='' method='POST'>
 58                 CWID: <input type='text' name='cwid'>
 59                 <input type='submit' value='Submit'><br>
 60         </form>
 61 </body>
 62 </html>
```

Comment: So, now what u want ??
viewing which output ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to get the results from my query with line 24. As they input a SSN, It should return with the title. Sorry if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$resultSet->fetch_assoc()` not `$resultSet->fetch_assoc($resultSet)`.

**EDIT:**
Oh, and you have assigned the result of the output to `$rows` when you used `$row['title']`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I just tried that and it didn't output anything for a result.

Comment: I believed that did fix my problem with the if statement, but its going directly to the else. I had inserted "Not available" when it could not find an ssn. It just spits out that now.

Comment: Kindly check your query and change `$ssn` to `$search`. Hope this finally works.